# Is there a developer guide on permissions for iOS 6?

Tags: ios, permissions, ios6, ios-permissions

As the question asks.

I'm looking for a guide on permissions. I've only developed for Android before and I was wondering if there was a guide similar to http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html

I'm not entirely sure how permissions work (or if they're even called this on iOS 6).

Comment: http://adcdownload.apple.com//wwdc_2012/wwdc_2012_session_pdfs/session_710__privacy_support_in_ios_and_os_x.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have permissions the way you do on Android, as in you must declare them some where on for hand.

When you, for example, start the locationmanager, the system will ask the user if your app is allowed to receive location updates. If the user does not allow this the the [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) will call the delegate that it could not retrieve any location updates.

There is also a methods on [`CLLocationManager`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html) called [`authorizationStatus`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW11) to check the current status. This is an [`CLAuthorizationStatus`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocationManager_Class/CLLocationManager/CLLocationManager.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007125-CH3-SW12).

Every other component will have a simulare kind of methods and error to check wether the user allows your app to acces data.

Comment: So is there no comprehensive place or guide that lists the components that will ask the user for permission? I'm basically after components that may require permission from the user to access data.

Comment: No there is no such thing on iOS. What kind of data are you after. Apple has really strict guidelines on getting user data.

Comment: I'm writing a report and it would be really useful to know what kind of components required permissions. I was hoping there would be some sort of mapping from the permissions to the components or vise versa.

Comment: Well not that I'm aware of, you could have look at the documentation at Apple's developers site. But there is just less user data you can access on iOS then Android. To my knowledge location, social networks, address book, Calendar, reminders, bluetooth and camera/images thats it. You can check then in privacy section of the settings app.